What is the meaning of this shlok?
Namaskar,
I need to understand the meaning of below shloka.

तीर्थानां तीर्थराजं च पावनानां तु पावनम्।
भक्तानामेकमाधारं सानंदं श्रीधरं भजे।।
आदिनारायणं विष्णुं ब्रह्माणं च वसिष्ठकम्।
श्रीरामं मारुतिं वन्दे रामदासं च श्रीधरम्।।
नमः शांताय दिव्याय सत्यधर्मस्वरूपिणे।
स्वानंदामृततृप्ताय श्रीधराय नमो नमः।।
श्रीधर स्वामी महाराजांच्या चरणी नम्र वंदना !


Note: Stackexchange answers require citation, but I couldn't find any source with translation. I am not a Sanskrit scholar or even proficient in it. From whatever little I know I will translate, please don't completely rely on this, just use it as a suggestion.

This is a prayer on Shreedhar Swamiji, about whom you can learn more here and here.


Shloka 1:

तीर्थानां तीर्थराजं च पावनानां तु पावनम्।

He who among the sacred rivers is the king of such rivers, purest among the pure

भक्तानामेकमाधारं सानंदं श्रीधरं भजे।।

He who is the single refuge of his devotees, He who is happy and content, on that Sridhara Swami, I meditate and sing about.

Shloka 2:

आदिनारायणं विष्णुं ब्रह्माणं च वसिष्ठकम्।

To Lord Adi Narayana Vishnu, to Lord Brahma and to Shree Vasishta Rishi

श्रीरामं मारुतिं वन्दे रामदासं च श्रीधरम्।।

To Lord Shree Rama, to Maruthi and to Shreedhara Swami who is servant of Lord Rama, I offer my salutations and praise.

Shloka 3:

नमः शांताय दिव्याय सत्यधर्मस्वरूपिणे।

I bow down to the one who is peaceful, divine, the embodiment of Truth and Righteousness

स्वानंदामृततृप्ताय श्रीधराय नमो नमः।।

To the one who is content in the ambrosial bliss of the Self, to such Shreedhara Swami, I bow down again and again.

श्रीधर स्वामी महाराजांच्या चरणी नम्र वंदना !

Humble praises and salutations to the holy feet of Shreedhara Swami Maharaj !
